# Determine if struct embeds another struct?

Tags: go, struct, composition

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if a given `interface{}` is either a struct that embeds a given struct as an anonymous field, or an instance of the given struct itself.

For example, if I have a struct `A`, and struct `B` embeds struct `A`, but struct `C` does not:

- struct `A` should be valid
- struct `B` should be valid
- struct `C` should not be valid

I've created a playground that I hope illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

https://play.golang.org/p/pCClhTyJehH

I've tried the following, but the `a,embedsA := v.(struct{A})` part doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

```golang
a,embedsA := v.(struct{A})
if embedsA {
   fmt.Printf("embedded: %v\n", a.A.Foo)
} else {
   a,isA := v.(A)
   if isA {
       fmt.Printf("instance: %v\n", a.Foo)
   } else {
       fmt.Printf("%v does not embed A\n",v) 
   }
}
```

EDIT: I assume I can do this with reflection, but I'm more so curious if I can do it **without** reflection.

Comment: Reflection is required to solve this problem.  Type assertions cannot be used to get the value of an embedded type.

Comment: @iLoveReflection your name makes me feel like you were paid to say this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to know whether a struct embeds another type versus just fulfills an interface?